# How to add comma into number in c#

Tags: c#

Using `String.Format` how can I ensure all numbers have commas eg `123000 = "1,23,000";`

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0,0}",amount);
```

I got output like

```
123,234,000
```

I don't want it. but I will expect output like

```
12,32,34,000
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to implement a custom number format provider...

Comment: use a regex, or write your own string conversion function

Comment: can you give simple example for that

Comment: On MSDN under the "," custom separator - ["The NumberGroupSeparator and NumberGroupSizes properties of the current NumberFormatInfo object determine ... the size of each number group."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ^ In other words, you have the wrong culture - Another [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ToString("N") instead of that. ToString("N") will print 2 decimal digits. To get rid of those two digits, you can use ToString("N0").

Edit: To separate digits two by two:

```
123123123123.ToString("#,#", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 2 } })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a format info that has different number group sizes:

```
NumberFormatInfo formatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatInfo.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 };

int amount = 123234000;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(formatInfo, "{0:N0}", amount));
```

Output:

```
12,32,34,000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int num=123234000;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() 
  { 
    NumberGroupSeparator=",",
    NumberGroupSizes=new int[]{3,2}
  },
"{0:#,#}", num));
```

output:

```
12,32,34,000
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
int NewAmount=123456;
String.Format("{0:##,##,##,###}", NewAmount)
```

Comment: The group separator specifier (`,`) can't be used like that to specify how large the groups are, so the result is `123,456`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to integer in the culture format en-IN
Try the following

```
String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:0,0}", amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
123456789.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to display as Indian currency. If it is so, this may help.

```
    string fare = "1234567";
    decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(fare, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    CultureInfo hindi = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    string text = string.Format(hindi, "{0:c}", parsed);
```